Is there a gender-neutral word for "friend" in Russian?
I learned that подруга means female friend and друг means male friend, so I wonder how to say friend when:

you don't know the friend's gender (like when one hears about someone else's friend);
you talk about a friend in general, not a specific person;
you don't want to reveal the friend's gender.



If you hear about another person's friend, you'll probably hear them say 'друг' or 'подруга' specifically.

If you want to talk about friends in general, use the plural, друзья.

You have to jump through hoops if you want to mention a person in Russian without revealing their gender. You might say 'кто-то, кого я хорошо знаю' (someone I know well) or 'один хороший человек'.



I thought that "Мой друг" could be aimed at a male and at a female. For instance, in  https://slova.org.ru/pasternak/razryvoangel/ (7) it seems to me that "Мой друг" is a female (see "Разочаровалась?" (6)). Am I wrong?

Bruno, I find this usage of "друг" poetic / archaic.

You can use "мой друг" to address your female friend, but you should not use it to mention her between a third pary.


In most cases, you'll know the gender of the other person's friend at the same very moment they introduce their friend to you.
If you're asking, you can use "друг". "Есть ли у тебя друг, которому ты можешь позвонить?" (Do you have a friend you can call?) is gender-neutral.
You can also use "человек" (person) or "кое-кто" (a certain someone) here. Still, it requires some clarification, so you'll have to use more than one word, e.g. "близкий мне человек / кое-кто близкий мне" (person close to me/someone close to me), "человек/кое-кто, кому я полностью доверяю" (person of trust), etc.


Also, it's common to refer to a woman as a "друг" in many cases. But not to mislead the others, it's often used with the name, which reveals the gender.
"Это Наташа, она мой друг" (It's Natasha, she's a friend of mine) is completely common.
More, lots of men prefer to use exactly this form when introducing their female friends to their wives or girlfriends, because "подруга" has a slight intent of a "girlfriend", while "друг" implies that there's no romance between them :)

The word друг is sometimes used for female friends, to indicate that she's just a friend rather than a girlfriend.  Here's an example from a Russian Q&A site (https://otvet.mail.ru/question/43361531):

здрасте! Вопрос: как правильно говорить, про девушку, с которой
дружишь: она моя подруга или мой друг?
Все завит от того, до какой степени эти дружеские отношения между
мужчиной и женщиной доходят? Если один раз переспал и больше не
хочется. Хочется только общаться, значит друг. Если переспал, потом
еще раз и еще, значит подруга. А если еще не было ничего, тогда вы еще
определяетесь. Хотя бывает такое, что не хочется в постель значит друг
однозначно. А если ты чувствуешь, влечение к ней как женщине, а она
говорит тебе, что ты ей только друг - значит уже и не подруга и не
друг.


Друг is a gender-neutral word like almost all Russian masculine words. In Russian there's a difference between the gender of a person (пол) and the gender of a word (род). And there's a rule: if you want to express yourself in a gender-neutral way, use the masculine gender.

An example of this in English is the current trend to refer to women as actors rather than actresses.

I would suggest using "кое-кто из числа моих друзей".
Or shorter, "кое-кто из моих друзей".
